# C#.Net blocking ou non-blocking?

Tags: c#, desempenho, socket

A biblioteca System.Net.Sockets, utilizando operações assíncrona tais como BeginReceive(), BeginRead() e BeginSend() funcionam de forma blocking ou non-blocking? Se eu tiver 100 conexões, serão 100 threads, sendo 1 thread para gerenciar cada envio e recebimento de pacotes?

Eu preciso desenvolver um servidor socket TCP em C# que seja capaz de manipular 500 conexões simultâneas e não seria boa idéia ter 500 threads rodando.

Código referencia: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Você conhece SignalR?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As chamadas assíncronas são *non-blocking* - não é o caso de que cada socket estará usando um *thread* particular. Você pode verificar isso com um teste simples (veja abaixo): no servidor você imprime o thread em que cada chamada do cliente é feita, e lança múltiplos clientes enviando dados. No exemplo abaixo, com 20 clientes o servidor usa apenas 3 threads diferentes. Dependendo do número de clientes enviando dados *simultaneamente* o gerenciamento dos callbacks dos sockets pode alocar mais threads pro *thread pool*, mas se você não tiver os 500 clientes enviando / recebendo dados ao mesmo tempo, você terá muito menos que 500 threads.

**Servidor**:

```
class Program
{
    static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(ipHostInfo.AddressList[0], 11000);
        Console.WriteLine("Local address and port : {0}", localEP.ToString());

        Socket listener = new Socket(localEP.Address.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEP);
            listener.Listen(10);

            while (true)
            {
                allDone.Reset();

                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                listener.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener);

                allDone.WaitOne();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Closing the listener...");
    }

    static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        // Signal the main thread to continue.
        allDone.Set();

        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.WorkSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.WorkSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket.
        int read = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        // Data was read from the client socket.
        if (read > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] read {1} bytes", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, read);
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, read));
            handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }
        else
        {
            if (state.sb.Length > 1)
            {
                // All the data has been read from the client;
                // display it on the console.
                string content = state.sb.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Read {1} bytes from socket.\n Data : {2}",
                   Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, content.Length, content);
            }
            handler.Close();
        }
    }

    public class StateObject
    {
        public Socket WorkSocket = null;
        public const int BufferSize = 1024;
        public byte[] Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
```

**Client**:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipHostInfo.AddressList[0], 11000);

        Socket s = new Socket(remoteEP.Address.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        s.Connect(remoteEP);

        Console.WriteLine("Connected, sending a few bytes...");
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello");
        s.Send(bytes);

        Console.Write("Now press ENTER to send remaining bytes...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(" world");
        s.Send(bytes);

        s.Close();
        s.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comando para rodar na linha de comando para iniciar vários (20 neste caso) clientes de uma vez:

```
for /l %i in (1,1,20) do start client.exe
```